# Turn off Google Maps local points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, point-of-interest

I currently have a webapp which draws points of interest using the maps api, however I have noticed a small annoyance which I would like to turn off if possible.

Right now when the google map is loaded, it will show points of interest and local business (city hall, pizza hut, etc...). I don't mind the wording showing up labelling them, but I do not want these points clickable, as if often happens that people using touchscreens hit these points accidentally

Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Comment: Can you accept the answer if that's what you were looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can turn them off using [map Styling](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/styling.html). The specific style would be

```
[
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```